# Enforcing policies from Atlassian Stash Repository merge request check plugin

Tags: plugins, pull-request, bitbucket-server

I need help on how to successfully create a `RepositoryMergeRequestCheck`

As part of our merge workflow, we need to ensure some policies about some files. Policies includes among others:

- File naming conventions of individual files
- File naming conventions between multiple files (for example, correlative-named files)
- Inspection of files to enforce or disallow usage of statements or functions

I want to be able to check for this policies on a repository merge request check so I’m building a plugin for Astlassian Stash

I have tried the following approaches:

- Using the `RepositoryMergeRequestCheckContext` parameter of `RepositoryMergeRequestCheck.check()`
  Since the method signature is:

  `@Override
  public void check(RepositoryMergeRequestCheckContext context)`

The first thing I tried using was the context parameter. I can say `context.getMergeRequest().getPullRequest().getFromRef().getRepository()` 
Now I get a Repository instance and I’m not sure how to extract commit info from it.

- Calling Git directly: Since this check was originally developed as a git hook script, calling git from the SDK made sense to me. It led me to this situation:

  `String result = gitScm.getCommandBuilderFactory().builder().lsTree().build(…).call();`

Where gitScm gets dependency injected in the plugin’s constructor.
Notice the build parameter? It expects a `CommandOutputHandler<T>` in this case T is string, but that’s an interface, and I’m not sure how to get an instance that implements that interface or how to create one.

- REST API
  REST API looks the easiest of them but it still doesn’t help with the third requirement  of inspecting file’s source code and also, spawning web requests from the merge request check that is itself a web request from stash doesn’t seem to be a good idea from the performance side.

What path should I follow or how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started writing you a response, and then realised that I'd already answered this on Answers (which was what I was going to suggest as well).

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/182943/enforcing-policies-from-repository-merge-request-check-plugin

Cheers,
Charles